# Dual graphics compatibility with AMD A-10 7850K?

Tags: graphics-card, compatibility

I see on AMD's official website that to use their Dual Graphics capability, the "recommended" pairing for an AMD A-10 7850K Kaveri APU is an AMD R7 250 series graphics card.

Question: To take full advantage of AMD's Dual Graphics capability, does my graphics card absolutely have to be a R7 250? For example, can I pair my 7850K APU with a R9 series card? Or where can I find a more detailed Dual Graphics compatibility chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pair an R9 with the APU, but you won't be able to take advantage of some of its more advanced features like VCE, DVI audio, Trueaudio while in crossfire with the APU. And it won't make a huge difference in performance having that setup or a standalone R9, while it will surely raise the risk for incompatibility application-wise.

When they "recommend" that card, I think it's to maximize the price/efficiency/compatibility relationship.

Comment: No, they recommend that card because it can crossfire with the APU. Yes you can use an R9 card with the APU and I would even recommend that, but it will not crossfire with the APU like the R7 250 would. I know this is an old question but... I thought that was important information to add.